# PHP function unavailable - may be missed APACHE compile config

Tags: php, apache

I have just switched from a shared hosting environment to a dedicated service and whilst testing my code I am finding that some PHP functions aren't available:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtoupper()
```

I have full access to WHM and I can recompile PHP with a bunch of options.  Being new to this, I felt it be better to leave the options I'm not familiar with as their default setting.

PHPINFO() states I am running version 5.2.9 and APACHE 2.2.

Have I missed an option in configuring APACHE - is there something I need to switch on to gain full access to PHP functions?

Comment: this is a question better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a question better asked on [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)

however, regarding your version you moust likely just have to activate mb extensions

also make sure your php is compiled with `--enable-mbstring`

Comment: Thanks for answering - much appreciated especially today.  This was the answer I was looking for.  Didn't realise there was a serverfault.com - but will keep that in mind for next time.