# Convert to uppercase Cyrillic

Tags: php, utf-8, cyrillic

I need to convert the Cyrillic string to uppercase. Function mb_strtouppe not found.

```
 Call to undefined function mb_strtoupper()
```

How can I do that?

How I can change uppercase for in Cyrillic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function unavailable - may be missed APACHE compile config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530620/php-function-unavailable-may-be-missed-apache-compile-config)

Comment: Also see [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419102/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen)

Answer (score 0):

`mbstring` is a PHP extension which is not enabled by default. The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) say:

> mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by
>   default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure
>   option. See the Install section for details.
>
> The following configure options are related to the mbstring module.
>
> ```
> --enable-mbstring : Enable mbstring functions. This option is required to use mbstring functions.
>
> libmbfl is necessary for mbstring. libmbfl is bundled with mbstring. Before PHP 7.3.0, if libmbfl is already installed on the
> ```
>
> system, --with-libmbfl[=DIR] can be specified to use the installed
>   library.
>
> ```
> --disable-mbregex : Disable regular expression functions with multibyte character support.
>
> Oniguruma is necessary for the regular expression functions with multibyte character support. Oniguruma is bundled with mbstring. As of
> ```
>
> PHP 5.4.0, if Oniguruma is already installed on the system,
>   --with-onig[=DIR] can be specified to use the installed library.
>
> ```
> As of PHP 5.4.0 it is possible to disable the multibyte regex backtrack check by specifying --disable-mbregex-backtrack .
> ```